# Crashlytics report upload crashed due java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, crash, out-of-memory, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have crash reported on Google console, there are two of them and it is identical (because stackoverflow detect it as spam, i will post only one), Crashlytics trying to upload report and it will be crashed due out of memory error.

Crash report:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
  at com.android.okio.Segment.<init> (Segment.java:34)
  at com.android.okio.SegmentPool.take (SegmentPool.java:48)
  at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.writableSegment (OkBuffer.java:511)
  at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.write (OkBuffer.java:424)
  at com.android.okio.OkBuffer.clone (OkBuffer.java:740)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RetryableSink.writeToSocket (RetryableSink.java:77)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.writeRequestBody (HttpConnection.java:236)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.writeRequestBody (HttpTransport.java:77)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse (HttpEngine.java:610)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:491)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode (DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode (HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.code (HttpRequest.java:1357)
  at com.crashlytics.android.core.DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.invoke (DefaultCreateReportSpiCall.java:65)
  at com.crashlytics.android.core.CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.invoke (CompositeCreateReportSpiCall.java:18)
  at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader.forceUpload (ReportUploader.java:104)
  at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.attemptUploadWithRetry (ReportUploader.java:242)
  at com.crashlytics.android.core.ReportUploader$Worker.onRun (ReportUploader.java:185)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run (BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:30)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Craslytics libs version used:
answers-1.4.6, beta-1.2.10, crashlytics-2.9.8, crashlytics-core-2.6.7, crashlytics-ndk-2.0.5, fabric-1.4.7

I don't know how to reproduce this crash, so i have no idea to fix it myself. Any tips to troubleshoot this kind of crash?

Answer (score 1):

this error show at that time when you do some this wrong or cause of you faulty programming.

Usually, this error is thrown when the Java Virtual Machine cannot allocate an object because it is out of memory, and no more memory could be made available by the garbage collector.

OutOfMemoryError usually means that you’re doing something wrong, either holding onto objects too long, or trying to process too much data at a time. Sometimes, it indicates a problem that’s out of your control, such as a third-party library that caches strings, or an application server that doesn’t clean up after deploys. And sometimes, it has nothing to do with objects on the heap.

To find the cause, the text of the exception includes a detailed message at the end. Lets examine all the errors.

1. Error 1 – Java heap space : This error arises due to the
   applications that make excessive use of finalizers.
2. Error 2 – GC Overhead limit exceeded : This error indicates that the
   garbage collector is running all the time and Java program is making
   very slow progress.
3. Error 3 – Permgen space is thrown : The java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
   PermGen space error indicates that the Permanent Generation’s area
   in memory is exhausted.
4. Error 4 – Metaspace : Java class metadata is allocated in native
   memory. If metaspace for class metadata is exhausted, a
   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception with a detail MetaSpace is
   thrown.
5. Error 5 – Requested array size exceeds VM limit : This error
   indicates that the application attempted to allocate an array that
   is larger than the heap size.
6. Error 6 – Request size bytes for reason. Out of swap space? : This
   apparent exception occurs when an allocation from the native heap
   failed and the native heap might be close to exhaustion. The error
   indicates the size (in bytes) of the request that failed and the
   reason for the memory request. Usually the reason is the name of the
   source module reporting the allocation failure, although sometimes
   it is the actual reason.
7. Error 7 : reason stack_trace_with_native_method : Whenever this
   error message(reason stack_trace_with_native_method) is thrown then
   a stack trace is printed in which the top frame is a native method,
   then this is an indication that a native method has encountered an
   allocation failure. The difference between this and the previous
   message is that the allocation failure was detected in a Java Native
   Interface (JNI) or native method rather than in the JVM code.

for more details [Understand the OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) 
and reference of answer [ref.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-outofmemoryerror-exception-java/)